# How to convert Redis Value[] into Deserialize object c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm working on list sorting in webjob.
It is working fine when i used c# List. But to increase performance i'm saving my data into Redis cache in the form of list.

my final target is only take out most recent last 5 minutes data.

working c# code -

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public uint InstrumentID { get; set; }
        public decimal Close { get; set; }
        public decimal High { get; set; }
        public decimal Low { get; set; }
        public decimal Open { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public uint Volume { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime Ttl { get; } = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
        public DateTime? Persisted { get; set; }

        public bool IsDead => DateTime.Now > Ttl;
        public bool IsPersisted => Persisted.HasValue;
        public bool TimeToPersist => IsPersisted == false && DateTime.Now > Created.AddMinutes(5);

        public DateTime GetStartOfPeriodByMins(int numMinutes)
        {
            int oldMinutes = TimeStamp.Minute;
            int newMinutes = (oldMinutes / numMinutes) * numMinutes;

            DateTime startOfPeriod = new DateTime(TimeStamp.Year, TimeStamp.Month, TimeStamp.Day, TimeStamp.Hour, newMinutes, 0);

            return startOfPeriod;
        }
    }

var inputList = new SortedSet<MyObject>(new MyObjectComparer());

            inputList.Add(new MyObject() { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Open = 9, High = 12, Low = 8, Close = 11, InstrumentID = 2526 });
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            inputList.Add(new MyObject() { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Open = 9, High = 12, Low = 8, Close = 11, InstrumentID = 2526 });
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            inputList.Add(new MyObject() { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Open = 9, High = 12, Low = 8, Close = 11, InstrumentID = 2526 });
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
            inputList.Add(new MyObject() { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Open = 9, High = 12, Low = 8, Close = 11, InstrumentID = 2526 });

            var resultSet = inputList
                .GroupBy(i => i.GetStartOfPeriodByMins(5))
                .Select(gr =>
               new
               {
                   StartOfPeriod = gr.Key,
                   Min = gr.Min(item => item.Open),
                   Max = gr.Max(item => item.Open),
                   Open = gr.OrderBy(item => item.TimeStamp).First().Open,
                   Close = gr.OrderBy(item => item.TimeStamp).Last().Open
               });
```

Now same records i'm continuously inserting into redis cache. and while tried to take last 5 minutes data I was thiking to use same `GetStartOfPeriodByMins` concept but it needs a list of MyObject class and redis return RedisValue[].

Redis code - using StackExchange.Redis package

```
var cache = RedisConnectorHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();

            //int i = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                var tickDataHis = new MyObject()
                {
                    InstrumentID = 2526,
                    Close = 14 + i,
                    High = 16 + i,
                    Low = 11 + i,
                    Open = 12 + i,
                    TimeStamp = DateTime.Now,
                    Volume = 11111
                };

                // insert into redis
                cache.ListRightPush("tickData", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tickDataHis));

                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }

            var inputList = cache.ListRange("tickData");
```

> or is there any other way to get latest 5 minutes data from redis
> cache?

[image]

Comment: I havent used StackExchange.Redis for a while but as far as I remember. It does not come built-in with a deseriliazer. So either you implement a case by case for your code or you can just use a JSON de/serializer.

Comment: I tried with json deserializer but it difficult to convert the data from Redis Value [] if you find any code snippet please share thanks

Comment: I used (I think) in the past this nuget package. https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Newtonsoft/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Redis to store timeseries data in the past. In order to optimize data retrieval, I used a sorted set (in that case there were more than one, but the concept is the same) where the score was the unix timestamp of when the data were recorded, and I serialized my data using `Newtonsoft.Json` library.

The code was something like this:

```
var myData = new MyObject() { SomeProperty = "my text" };
long dataTimestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
string serializedData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.Convert(myData);
redisDb.SortedSetAdd("mySortedSet", dataTimestamp, serializedData);
```

Doing in this way, if you want to retrieve **only** the data of the last 5 minutes, you can directly filter the data loaded from Redis using `SortedSetRangeByScore` method and passing "now - 5 minutes" as starting score, so that you can deserialize only what you need (which is of course less expensive than deserializing the whole list):

```
var minutesToTake = 5;
long startingTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(-minutesToTake).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
RedisValue[] redisData = redisDb.SortedSetRangeByScore("mySortedSet", startingTime);
```

After that you can easily deserialize your data with the help of linq (consider that `RedisValue` implements operator to string conversion):

```
MyObject[] myData = redisData.Select(d => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(d)).ToArray();
```

**Edit**: I didn't use the package suggested by @Hasan Emrah Süngü. Maybe it is more efficient, I'm just explaining what I did at that time.

**Edit 2**: `redisDb` is my `StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase` instance.

**Edit 3**: Useful reference links:

- data persistence on Redis: https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-expires-keys-with-limited-time-to-live
- Redis sorted sets: https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-sorted-sets
- sorted sets for timeseries: https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/time-series/sorted-set-time-series/

Comment: my only question is what if my redis cache is continuously updating with new data and i'm trying to get latest 5 minutes data after every 5 minute is it ok ?

Comment: @Neo it works, since it will keep getting the latest data and only those data will be deserialized, but I suggest to thing about some retention policy. Redis gives you the possibility to set a TTL on the keys (see here https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-expires-keys-with-limited-time-to-live) but unfortunately not on the single items of lists and sets. [Continue in the next comment]

Comment: @Neo Once you have decided a TTL for your data, you have 2 possibilities: you can create a timer, that will delete data older than your desired persistence (using the method `SortedSetRemoveRangeByScore`, passing score from 0 to "now - TTL"), or you can create more sets (dividing by minute/hour, as it is better for you) setting the desired TTL on the keys, but in this case you have to change the loading logic, since you need to consider multiple sets in order to retrieve all the data you need. I put some useful reference links in the answer.